# Reserve shopware basket items

Tags: php, payment, cart, shopware

Has anybody ever had this following issue?

Prerequisites:
There is only one item of item A left in stock.

1. Customer 1 puts an item A into the basket and proceeds to the checkout.
2. Customer 1 is redirected to the payment service provider (PSP) site
3. In the meantime Customer 2 puts item A into his basket and proceeds to the checkout
4. Customer 2 is redirected to the (PSP) site
5. Both Customers pay for the item successfully.
6. Stock left is -1

Is there any native way to prevent this? To reserve the item in the basket before the customer is redirected? Is there any way to restore the stock if the payment was unsuccesful?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your checkout works, but you could change the status of the cart/order when the customers loads the checkout page. This way you can collect the quantity of "reserved" items and subtract that from the stock in the product table. Use an timestamp when you set the new status for the cart so that you can filter old cart that has been canceled or abandoned.

Comment: It is standard shopware checkout. I surely can get around it and fiddle with the database objects. But just before I do that I thought I could ask the community if there are any built in methods. The Basket object doesn't have any method called reserve.